# Why is this weighted sum of binomials with alternating signs simplifies?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have stumbled upon this relation but can't figure out why this is so:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^i (-1)^{k-1} \binom{i}{k} \frac{k}{n-i+k} = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{i}}
$$

Can anyone shows how this is the case? Is this a known relation?

Comment: If you plug in n=2, i=2, it doesn't hold. Where did you find the relation?

Comment: @Blueyedaisy: sorry a typo: I edited to put a +k, not -k in denominator.

Comment: Using $\binom ik k=I\binom{i-1}{k-1},$ this is equivalent to $$\sum_{k=1}^{i}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{i-1}{k-1}\frac1{n+(k-i )}=\frac1{n\binom{n-1}{i-1}}$$ But that doesn’t seem any easier.  Maybe 5e left hand can be seen as a Cauchy product of two series?

Comment: Wikipedia describes (essentially) this as [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Partial_fraction_decomposition) of the reciprocal of binomial coefficients.

Comment: Maybe multiply both sides by $\binom{n}{i}$ and interpret the resulting identity as an inclusion-exclusion formula.

Comment: @prets You are indeed correct, this is the second form reported on your link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since, for $p\geq 1$, $$\int_0^1 x^{p-1} dx= \frac 1 p$$

$$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=1}^i (-1)^{k-1} \binom{i}{k} \frac{k}{n-i+k} &= \int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^i (-1)^{k-1} \binom{i}{k} kx^{n-i+k-1}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 x^{n-i}\sum_{k=1}^i (-1)^{k-1} \binom{i}{k} kx^{k-1}dx\\
&= -\int_0^1 x^{n-i}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{k=0}^i (-1)^{k} \binom{i}{k} x^{k}\right)dx\\
&=-\int_0^1 x^{n-i}\frac{d}{dx}\left[\left(1-x\right)^i\right]dx\\
&= i\int_0^1 x^{n-i}\left(1-x\right)^{i-1}dx\\
\end{split}$$
Using the [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties) of the Beta function, which can be proven by integration by parts,
$$\int_0^1 x^{n-i}(1-x)^{i-1}dx=B(n-i+1, i)=\frac{n+1}{(n-i+1)i}\frac 1 {n+1 \choose i}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^i (-1)^{k-1} \binom{i}{k} \frac{k}{n-i+k}=\frac{n+1} {n-i+1}\frac 1 {n+1 \choose i}=\frac 1 {n \choose i}$$

Comment: GREAT response! The demonstration is very clear and so useful for my other problems at hand.

Comment: Thanks! The trick of converting to an integral to gain linearity is often useful.